# How to make DAL integration tests less brittle?

Tags: c#, .net, integration-testing, data-access-layer

First. We do not use ORM. And won't use it in near future. (it's not my decision).

We create stored procedures for multiple read/write cases.
Most of the reading SPs are for populating DTOs which are sent to client.

Each DAL method usually calls single SP.
Integration test consists of running insert script, then initialization of expectations  according to the script, calling method and then checking returned result. I.e. standard AAA pattern.

However, even small DB schema refactoring usually breaks about a hundred of tests.
Prepare are the cause: whereas DTO usually needs a subset of columns. Insert requires all of them. Thus every ыскшзе that touches refactored table breaks.

I consider correcting bunch of the scripts every time after refactoring a kind of monkey job. Looking for ways of improving tests robustness.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to write generalized functions that prepare one table and use this always instead of repeating the prepare statements across your tests.

Also you could look into T4 template with interaction to the database to generate the prepare statements before compiling the tests.

[Generate from T4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787460/using-t4-templates-to-generate-multiple-classes-based-on-poco)

Comment: DTOs are quite often composed of data from several tables. I also consider approach of having one script for populating database and then running all reading DAL methods. Execution sequence here does not matter as DB's state is not changed. Unfortunately there are some problems with DB generated values which sometimes are the part of test expectations.

Comment: But for these situations separate script is ok =)

Comment: The solution still can work if you make something like a T4 generator for each DTO instead of each table. The idea is the limit the places where changes occur, but sometimes it can be a struggle to seperate everything in generator classes, but once done all your testing code will be much stable